# Loading a new Menu control in a control array with submenus

Tags: menu, vb6, submenu

I have a menu `Mnu1` which contains two sub-menus. This menu item is array part of a control array - I have added the index entry for `Mnu1` equal to zero. Now when I create more menus in the array `Mnu1` using the Load statement, they get created, but they don't contain the sub menus that were in `Mnu1(0)`. How can I can load more instances of `Mnu1()` automatically with these sub-menus?

Current Menu Structure is:

```
Mnu

---Mnu1     (with index=0)

-------Mnu1a

-------Mnu1b

---Mnu2

---Mnu3
```

After using `Load (mnu(1))`

```
Mnu

---Mnu1     (with index=0)

-------Mnu1a

-------Mnu1b

---Mnu1     (with index=1)

---Mnu2

---Mnu3
```

Required menu structure

```
Mnu

---Mnu1     (with index=0)

-------Mnu1a

-------Mnu1b

---Mnu1     (with index=1)

-------Mnu1a

-------Mnu1b

---Mnu2

---Mnu3
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you just can't do this. You have the idea that you are somehow copying Mnu1(0), but this is not what is happening. Instead, you are simply adding a new vanilla Menu control into the same level of the hierarchy as Mnu1(0), just so you have the convenience of being able to refer to the Menu control via an index.

The native VB way of doing what you want is to create your menu structure using all the controls that you would ever use, if that is possible. You then initially set the Visible property of your currently unwanted menu control to False. When you want to see your control, set Visible = True.

The only other way of doing this is to use Windows API calls (GetMenu(), GetSubMenu(), InsertMenu()) to create new underlying menu items, and then subclass the window to receive the WM_COMMAND messages.

Comment: Thanks for response, I have decided to use something else.

Comment: @user2265784 What did you use?

Comment: I created two menus `Mnu1a` and `Mnu1b` under `Mnu`. Then created `Mnu1` inside them.